# how to insert the selected rows of GridView with CheckBox in a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The Idea is to select values from 5 dropdownlist on a page 
and pass these values to a stored procedure as parameters in the database.
stored procedures select matching rows based on these parameters from a table 
in the database and 
a grid veiw is on the page will filled with these selected rows.

now the second step is :
To have a button which when clicked, a loop will be executed over GridView Rows. 
Within the loop we will check whether the CheckBox for that row is checked, 
if the CheckBox is checked then the Value from the GridView Rows that are checked
will be fetched and inserted into another table of database.

i am using 3 layered architecture.
please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a little insight into your current code for this? Are you using MVC? Are your checkboxes bound to a model?

Comment: My first and probably very naiv idea is that if the checkbox is checked you pass the ID (or something which serves as a PK in the first table) to a stored procedure. This procedure then selects the given row from the first table and inserts the data to the new table.